# Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewHolder' Java Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder, notepad

[image: Error of Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewHolder']

I have tried other examples online and in stack overflow but cannot solve this issue I was following a tut made years ago which uses ViewHolder but it gives me error "Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewHolder'"
this is for a part of my notepad tool inside of a app I'm making any help is appreciated

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NotesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, please post source code as text, not screenshots -- that makes it easier to search, read, and (where relevant) copy that source code.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Adapter.ViewHolder` to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the error occurs for `Adapter.ViewHolder`. The program is expecting a class called `Adapter` to have a nested class called `ViewHolder`, which it does not.

I suspect you want to use the `ViewHolder` inside your `NotesAdapter` class. To use that class, all you will need to do is change `Adapter.ViewHolder` to `NotesAdapter.ViewHolder`.

Comment: ah yes that makes since I was using a different name and didn't realize